# How to execute Javascript from ActiveX in IE

Tags: activex, npapi

I have a javascript for example

```
try { __flash__toXML(onYouTubePlayerReady("")) ; } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; } .
```

In FireFox, Adobe plugin(Flash player plugin) executes above Java Script  by calling `NPN_Evaluate` and `NPN_Evaluate()` returns result also.

I am not getting how in IE, adobe flash player(ActiveX) executes the above and same JAVA script. But I am seeing a result in SetReturnValue() of IShockwaveFlash like `</undefined>`, `<string>3456</string>`. It looks like Adobe ActiveX is not using `IHTMLWindow2::execScript()` to execute JS.

I would like to know how to execute the JS code from ActiveX.

I know how to call a JS function with the help of `IHTMLWindow2::execScript()`. But `IHTMLWindow2::execScript()` does not returns result. Also I know How to call a JS function with the help of `IDispatch()` interfaces.

I would like to know how Adobe ActiveX is executing the above code. I am also developing a similar ActiveX for IE and I would like to execute similar kind of JS(above one) from ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX uses IE's IHTMLWindow2::execScript() to execute javascript, but IHTMLWindow2::execScript() do not return result. It uses IshockwaveFlash::SetRerernValue and IShockwaveFlash::CallFunction to return javascript result.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do what you're asking to do; at least if there is it is fairly new and only works on newer versions of IE (I haven't looked hard recently).  One option, however, is to wrap the script in a function call and save the result of that call to some global variable (on window) that you can then query to get the return value.

I don't know for sure, but I would guess that this is something along the lines of what flash is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do agree SWFObject is the best method, you can pass the values through the `'src'` and `'movie'` params. EX:

```
'src', '/resources/flash/corporateWebsitButtons?variable=value&variable2=value'
'movie', '/resources/flash/corporateWebsitButtons?variable=value&variable2=value'
```